# selectable filtering in jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I would like to filter `<div>` children from this list item to not get selected, only the entire `<li>`.

The HTML structure would be like:

```
<ul id="selectable">
   <li>
     <div id="1"></div>
     <div id="2"></div>
   </li>
   <li>
     <div id="1"></div>
     <div id="2"></div>
   </li>
   ...
</ul>
```

The jQuery would be:

```
var foo = $('#selectable').selectable({
    filter: " > div"
});
```

But it's not working, happens that... if I don't put any filtering, I would be selecing the `<div>`s inside it, specially the `<div>` with the `id=2` which is out the container gets selected, and it's awful! Here’s a screenshot so you can understand what I'm saying:

[image: Screenshot]

See the "About" text being selected too? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
var foo = $('#selectable').selectable({
    filter: " li " // li in place of div
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to filter by "li" in the selectable.

Comment: Although this answer was earlier than Rohan's answer, I think the latter is nicer and should be accepted instead.